# How to reproject using gdal.warp

Tags: python, gdal, gdalwarp

I am trying to reproject the raster data to "EPSG:4326", but getting this error :
`RuntimeError: Translating source or target SRS failed: EPSG:4326`

and my code is:

```
filename = 'mosaic_band1_1.tif'
input_raster = gdal.Open(filename)
output_raster = 'mosaic_band1_1_rep.tif'
warp = gdal.Warp(output_raster,input_raster,dstSRS='EPSG:4326')
warp = None
```

GDAL version 2.4.1

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: mosaic_band1_2.tif
Size is 7200, 4800
Coordinate System is:
PROJCRS["unnamed",
    BASEGEOGCRS["Unknown datum based upon the custom spheroid",
        DATUM["Not_specified_based_on_custom_spheroid",
            ELLIPSOID["Custom spheroid",6371007.181,0,
                LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,
                    ID["EPSG",9001]]]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
                ID["EPSG",9122]]]],
    CONVERSION["Sinusoidal",
        METHOD["Sinusoidal"],
        PARAMETER["Longitude of natural origin",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8802]],
        PARAMETER["False easting",0,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8806]],
        PARAMETER["False northing",0,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8807]]],
    CS[Cartesian,2],
        AXIS["easting",east,
            ORDER[1],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,
                ID["EPSG",9001]]],
        AXIS["northing",north,
            ORDER[2],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,
                ID["EPSG",9001]]]]
Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 1,2
Origin = (3335851.558999999891967,6671703.117999999783933)
Pixel Size = (463.312716527916677,-463.312716527916507)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
Corner Coordinates:

Upper Left  ( 3335851.559, 6671703.118) ( 60d 0' 0.00"E, 60d 0' 0.00"N)
Lower Left  ( 3335851.559, 4447802.079) ( 39d 9'43.99"E, 40d 0' 0.00"N)
Upper Right ( 6671703.118, 6671703.118) (120d 0' 0.00"E, 60d 0' 0.00"N)
Lower Right ( 6671703.118, 4447802.079) ( 78d19'27.97"E, 40d 0' 0.00"N)
Center      ( 5003777.339, 5559752.598) ( 70d 0'27.26"E, 50d 0' 0.00"N)
Band 1 Block=7200x1 Type=Int16, ColorInterp=Gray
  NoData Value=255
Band 2 Block=7200x1 Type=Int16, ColorInterp=Undefined
  NoData Value=255
Band 3 Block=7200x1 Type=Int16, ColorInterp=Undefined
  NoData Value=255
```

Comment: Check with gdalinfo or with Python that GDAL can find the source SRS.

Comment: how can I check that?

Comment: With the command line utility `gdalinfo mosaic_band1_1.tif`.

Comment: @user30184 edited the info

Comment: I think you should write mail to proj-users mailing list https://lists.osgeo.org/mailman/listinfo/proj. Perhaps the non-standard source coordinate system requires some special tricks `PROJCRS["unnamed",
    BASEGEOGCRS["Unknown datum based upon the custom spheroid",
        DATUM["Not_specified_based_on_custom_spheroid",
            ELLIPSOID["Custom spheroid",6371007.181,0,`